# Show more/less on PHP value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The code:

```
<p><?= $row['courseInfo']; ?></p>
```

How to make a show more/less button with a limited number of characters. But when touched show more shows all the text there is, when show less it goes back to the limited number of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JS method. I will work on controlling the character count but for now....

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let rm = document.querySelectorAll('.readmore');
  rm.forEach(el => {
    let oheight = el.offsetHeight;
    el.classList.add('less');
    if (oheight === el.offsetHeight) return el.classList.remove('less');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='rmlink' onclick='toggleRM(this)'>Read more</a>";
    el.append(div);

  })
}

function toggleRM(el) {
  const cl = el.parentNode.parentNode.classList
  const is_less = cl.contains('less');
  el.innerHTML = !is_less ? "Read More" : "Read Less";
  if (is_less) cl.remove('less');
  else cl.add('less');
}
```

```css
.readmore {
  max-width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

.readmore.less {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='readmore'>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
  animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
  est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
  voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</div>

<div class='readmore'>This one shouldn't truncate, it's short.</div>
```

Comment: And where is the show more/less button in this

Comment: @ZgjimGrajqevci - new answer - completely updated

Comment: Thank you soo muchh man. It's perfect, it would be amazing to have that character count but it can work with this too.

Comment: No this is even more amazing it limits the number of characters based on width.

Comment: Ok I just mark it, but I would like to see one with limited characters too if u could I mean.

Comment: I think it's possible but it gets a bit sticky with the css - this whole approach relies on css rules. Check this out: https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-truncation-with-pure-css/

Comment: Because max-width or auto width is not working

Comment: Is there an easy way to hide the "Read More" button if the whole texte is already displayed? For instance, if the text is small, we don't need a "Read More" button; or if we remove the `max-width` and have a large monitor.

Comment: @4wk_ - sure there are probably a couple ways. I just added one to my answer - measure the height of the original div, then truncate it will css and measure again. If the 2 are the same, remove that css. It's a little bit of a hack, but I believe it should work just fine